# Error on compile to Andriod when apply certificate

Tags: codenameone

My app compile for android ok.

When I create the android certificate, and send to the codename compiler it don´t compile.

I tried to generate the certificate with the keytool and tried with the assitant on codenameone, the result is similar.

If I delete the keystore file and resend to the dashboard, the app compile ok.

This is the log errors

```
    Note: there were 3 references to unknown classes.
      You should check your configuration for typos.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
    Note: there were 1 references to unknown class members.
      You should check your configuration for typos.
    Note: there were 22 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
      (using '-keep').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#descriptorclass)
    Note: there were 17 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
    Note: there were 5 class casts of dynamically created class instances.
      You might consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes and/or
      their implementations (using '-keep').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclasscast)
    Warning: there were 25 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
    Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
        Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings 
  first.
    :transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
    :transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 3.21 secs.
    
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
    > Job failed, see logs for details
    
    * Try:
    Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Exception is:
    org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task 
   ':transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
        at
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the certificate. It fails in the obfuscation stage before the certificate. These errors are notoriously hard to read and it seems you snipped it a bit too late. I need the section above that which includes the detailed warning about the class/method that isn't found.

Go to the error and scroll a bit higher and look for a familiar class name with a proguard warning next to it. This is the class causing a problem probably because of a missing dependency. If you can't find it just post the log link to the website chat and our support will look over that for you.

Comment: Thanks Shai, 

reading this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49885112/proguard-server-build-error-codename-one

I tried with the hint: android.enableProguard=false and the compilation works.

Comment: I checked the log again and found this errors: 
Note: com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLib: can't find dynamically referenced class com.android.installreferrer.api.InstallReferrerClient
Note: com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLib: can't find dynamically referenced class android.os.SystemProperties

Then I checked the references because appflyer and cn1.lib, we used it time ago.

I deleted the jar and works the compilation with android.enableProguard=false. I think that is better use progard for prodduction enviroments.  you agree?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes. It's pretty important to use obfuscation for size/performance/security and portability since it detects problems that might fail on other platforms.